# Is "She is under the shower" a proper English sentence?

Tags: expressions, translation

There is currently a [debate on Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/12605081) about the proper translation of a sentence to English (the original language isn't the point of this question).

The sentence, literally translates to "She is under the shower". 
Now, in no English that I have heard is this correct. Possible appropriate interpretations would be:

- She is taking a shower
- She is in the shower

However, I thought I would put it to a wider audience for analysis. So:

Is "She is under the shower" a proper English sentence?

Comment: "She is under the shower" - that is a proper English sentence but it doesn't mean she is washing herself using the shower. It means that she is physically positioned under the shower, either the shower head itself or in a room below, therefore its expectation is fairly rare. One might infer that the water is running or that she is washing herself, but those are not the primary meanings of the sentence. If intended to mean she is taking a shower, it sounds bad/wrong.

Comment: **She is in the shower** is idiomatic. If you say, someone is **under the shower of criticism** "metaphorically", it could make sense, but it is not broadly used.

Comment: 'He is in the bath' would be unremarkable for 'He is taking/having a bath' (except for perhaps being a little personal) in the UK. 'He is under the shower', though formally nearly identical, is rare for the ablution sense. And  'She is at the basin' vanishingly rare.

Comment: The grammar is correct but no one says that.  There shouldn't be any debate.  She is in the shower or she is taking a shower.

Comment: @Rathony - In that metaphorical use, it would probably be _under **a** shower of criticism_. Great usage point, though.

Comment: "She is under the shower" doesn't work as an idiomatic expression in English, because in the context, "shower" refers to the entire space in which one washes him/herself, not just the spray of water.  A shower is generally a square or rectangular enclosure with a glass door (or possibly a curtain).  In it, there is a shower head providing a flow of water.  Sometimes the shower head is in a bathtub, in which case one could say equally correctly "He/she is in the tub" or "in the shower" when someone is washing under the flow of the water.

Comment: This is an expression I use (Scottish English), and Google backs me up with (moderately NSFW, so no link) a good number of matches to stock photos, etc.

Comment: Ok, now we have a hint that this is a regional idiom

Comment: @KenY-N I think that might deserve a separate answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The noun [**shower**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shower) doesn't have the same meaning in the two sentences.

1. She is taking a **shower**:

> An **act of washing** oneself in a shower: '*she had a nice refreshing
>   shower*'

2. She is in the **shower**:

> A **cubicle** or **bath** in which a person stands under a spray of water to
>   wash: '*A woman stood in the shower washing herself off after her day of work'*.

You don't say, "She is **under** the room/bathroom." when she is **in** the room/bathroom. That's why it is not idiomatic to say, "She is **under** the shower."

As commented above, if you say, "She is **under the shower** of criticism (praise).", *shower* would mean "a large number of things that fall or happen at the same time", but it is not idiomatic. You should use "She is **under a shower** of criticism (praise)."

If you say "She is under the shower," people would take it as "She is taking a shower." under normal circumstances, but it is neither idiomatic nor proper.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: I'm baffled as to why this has any downvotes and why the "answer" that doesn't answer the question has any upvotes. Did ELU and ELL somehow swap last night while I was asleep?

Comment: "She is in the shower" would be understood by the vast majority of US English speakers, in a normal context, to mean the same as "she is taking a shower".  It might be different if "the shower" is a large communal shower or some such, but for the normal home shower the two have virtually identical meaning.

Comment: (We all know the difference between "under" and "in", but that has little relevance when it comes to idioms.)

Comment: But there are three sentences involved here. In the first, "She is under the shower", the sense of _shower_ involved is the shower-head or the actual spray. The literal interpretation is available, as Mitch comments. So 'You don't say, "She is under the room/bathroom." when she is in the room/bathroom. That's why it is not idiomatic to say, "She is under the shower." ' is specious reasoning. Prepositional usages are often far from this transparent.

Comment: My point being that one can explain the meaning and usage of any English expression, but it doesn't necessarily mean there is only one interpretation. The OP's example is idiomatic in Italian, but it is still a grammatical and "proper" English sentence nevertheless.

Comment: "Under **a** shower of criticism" has 32.8k google hits, and is a common idiom.  "Under **the** shower of criticism" has only 4 google hits, and 3 of them are posts on this question.  It's only usable when there is a specific shower of criticism being discussed, like in the google hit: *Under the shower of criticism President Reagan has now announced he will ask Congress to enact legislation ...*.  You should never say *She is under the shower of criticism*.  That doesn't work, because there isn't a shower of criticism that everyone has the way people have bathrooms.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you are right. The Original Poster specifically asked about **under the shower** and I just quoted it as a **possible** example. I further added it is not as idiomatic as **under a shower of criticism**.

Comment: Your answer still claims that ""She is under the shower of criticism."  is a valid sentence that you *could* use, even though it's not idiomatic.  I don't think it is.  Unlike "She is under the shower", which still makes senese (and sounds oddly specific and personal), it just sounds wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes "32.8k google hits": That count is a *very* rough heuristic. If you page forward in [the results](https://www.google.com/search?q="Under+a+shower+of+criticism"), Google actually turns up less than 20 results. "Under a shower of criticism" really isn't a common idiom. http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/google-result-counts-are-a-meaningless-metric.html http://www.kilgarriff.co.uk/Publications/2007-K-CL-Googleology.pdf http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/21298

Comment: -1 *If you say "She is under the shower," people would take it as "She is taking a shower." under normal circumstances* Could you clarify **who** these "people" are? I'm a native speaker and I wouldn't take it that way.

Comment: @GoDucks I don't have to convince you. You don't seem to understand what **under normal circumstances** means.

Comment: And you my friend have little conception of what is idiomatic and intuitive and "normal"  to a native speaker.

Comment: @GoDucks - I'm a native English speaker. I would never say "she is under the shower", but if I heard someone else say it I'd assume they meant "she is taking a shower". Anecdotal evidence says that "she is in the shower" is the most common phrasing here in Australia.

Answer (score 17):

You are correct. Nobody says “she is under the shower” in English, even though she is technically under the shower head.

You *take a shower*, or you *have a shower*, or you may *be showering*, or you may be said to be *in the shower*, with the assumption being you are taking a shower.

Comment: I think one reason why no one says "under the shower" is because "the shower" never means "the shower head". So even if a person is literally underneath a shower head, one would still not say "she is under the shower" instead of "she is under the shower head".

Comment: In one instance I can see this working. If you have a workplace that has a safety shower for washing off chemical spills or radioactive dust, the shower in that case does not have any kind of enclosure. It that case "is IN the shower" would not make sense. "I heard Jim got toxic waste on him, where is he now?" "He's under the shower."

Comment: +1 "She is under the shower" is valid but it means "I'm very sorry for my crime; twenty years of prison have taught me the error of my ways, and I'm finally prepared to tell you where I hid the body."

Answer (score 11):

It is an idiomatic saying in Italian, "[stare sotto la doccia](https://www.google.it/search?q=stare%20sotto%20la%20doccia&oq=stare%20sotto%20la%20doccia&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22ero%20sotto%20la%20doccia%22%20in%20inglese)" (to be under the shower), and Italian speakers understand perfectly that the person is not being squashed by the shower cubicle, the person is "under" (below) the *jet* of running water.

There are 100s of English phrasal verbs and idioms which cannot and should not be understood literally, e.g. "The aeroplane took off" An Italian might protest: What did the plane ‘take off’? How can a plane ‘take something off’? Or, the extremely common English idiom: "*[under the weather](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/under+the+weather)*", is someone literally outside standing under a thing called "weather"? No, but English speakers understand it to mean that someone is either hungover or not feeling well. It's an idiom.

Although the OP's sentence “She is under the shower” is idiomatic for Italian speakers, English native speakers will prefer using the preposition *in*. As can be seen in the first link. However, I did find a couple of instances on the net where "under a/the shower" was used. It doesn't mean the OP's phrase is idiomatic in English, but it confirms the phrase is indeed “proper English”.

1. I have lingered **under a hot, pulsating shower**, all lathered up with a loofah and artisan peppermint-and-grapefruit soap. ([*‘Glamping’ removes all the roughing-it from camping*](http://www.laketahoenews.net/2012/06/glamping-removes-all-the-roughing-it-from-camping/))
2. I have been washing my hair under a veil of silence. Well, I've been **washing it under a shower**, but also under a metaphorical veil (*[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2012/oct/07/beauty-soothing-shampoo-itchy-scalp)*)
3. If she does leave her room it will only be to **stand under the shower** for a half an hour, a daily routine which requires the output of a power station and the contents of a reservoir. Then she still has to wash her hair later. (*[Losing the technology struggle](http://www.exeterexpressandecho.co.uk/Losing-technology-struggle/story-15977369-detail/story.html)*)
4. During a getaway to Egypt, for instance, my husband developed an unexpected fever. When a quick check showed a temperature approaching 106, I knew it was serious enough to put him **under a cold shower** while I ran downstairs to coordinate an ice delivery and a pharmacy run. (*[The Frugal Traveler](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/2013-04-08/travel/vs-frugal-traveler-first-aid-kit-20130408_1_travel-gear-the-frugal-traveler-medical-supplies)*)

Comment: One more thing to add is when you say "The airplane took off", the object of the phrasal verb to *take off*, i.e., **runway** or **airstrip** is elided. To take off has a sense of **become airborne** as it takes itself off a runway. I don't agree that it is one of the idioms that cannot be understood literally. Many phrasal verbs don't take the obvious objects for conciseness' sake.

Comment: @Rathony I would go as far as to say that "under the shower" is not idiomatic at all. I'm pretty sure I've never heard that phrase used.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: What you claim was never the question. The question was whether "She is under the shower" is a correct English sentence. The question was never whether this was the idiomatic way to express that someone is showering.

Answer (score 3):

If I read "She's under the shower" I find it to be valid and start thinking about being on the next floor below it. So yes, it has a meaning, but not the meaning you expect.

Many answers have already covered the expected phrase is "in the shower".

On further reflection, maybe you want "She's under the showerhead."

Answer (score 3):

Consider the question: *Where is she?*

If *anyone* (native speaker or not) said *She is under the shower*, I would probably ask *What do you mean?* The sentence is grammatically correct but not idiomatic. It does not mean *She is taking a shower* or *She is in the shower*, which are idiomatic and need no explanation.

(American English)

Answer (score 2):

As many comments suggest, it's certainly not a *normal* way to phrase it in English. However, it is both grammatically correct and gets the correct point across.

As Rathony points out, the term "shower" can refer to the act of showering, or the room/stall in which you shower. But it can also refer to a bunch of water droplets being sprayed in a direction. "A light shower" refers to rain showering down. "A shower of confetti" is slightly figurative, in that we've exchanged water droplets with bits of paper, but is basically literal in use. From this, we can conclude that a shower in this context is really a collection of small things flowing or falling in a general direction.

So saying "she's under the shower" means she's under the collection of water droplets that are spraying out of (and presumably down from) the shower head that's located inside the shower stall that's inside the shower/bath room.

It also passes basic grammar tests with a subject, a verb, and a perfectly acceptable prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a nice swimming pool with all kinds of nice water related things. One of these is a shower: Just an opening in the wall with huge amounts of water coming out. You are not *in* the shower. It's all in the open. You are not under the *showerhead*. There is no showerhead. You are *under the shower*. And enjoy it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I see nothing wrong with this answer. It makes it perfectly clear that the sentence is grammatically correct but would not be the normal idiom used by a native speaker to describe the act of washing oneself in the shower. It is possible to contrive a case where a native speaker might say it.

Comment: @steveverrill: Some people think that language must be boring. I think you should have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

While "*under* the shower" would generally not be used, there can be specific contexts where it would be appropriate.

For example, Joe answers the phone, and it's for Barry. Joe calls out to ask where Barry is. Barry calls back "I'm *in the shower*." [Location is clear, but activity is ambiguous].

Joe isn't sure whether this means Barry is merely in the bathroom or he's actually washing himself, and calls back "Can you take a phone call?" Barry calls back, somewhat annoyed, "No, I told you already, I'm *taking a shower*!" [Activity is now clear].

Joe talks further on the phone and discovers that the matter is both confidential and urgent. Joe takes the phone into the bathroom and says "I think you need to take this." Barry says crossly, "Joe, I'm actually *under the shower* at the moment. Tell them to wait a second!" [Specifying that Barry is located directly under the fall of water from the shower rose].

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is, but it would need to be in the right context.

Here's what i came up with

> My sister and I damaged the floor in the bathroom, and we spent the next two days fixing it. I was working under the toilet and basin. She was under the shower.

Comment: This appears to be answering only the *title* of the question; the rest of it makes clear that the author is really trying to judge if this sentence is valid and means what they think it does. Your answer doesn't have a lot of explanation, but it appears to be assuring them that it's valid by giving an example where the phrase has a different meaning.

Comment: You're being daft. The question told us how a sentence in another language would be "literally translated". From that description we have not the slightest idea what that sentence means, because it is not in English.

Comment: @gnasher729 - The original question (which does not appear to have been edited) says that "Possible appropriate interpretations would be: She is taking a shower; She is in the shower." So we do know what the original non-English sentence means.